# ie7 position absolute

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-position

This [code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Qcum5/) works fine in FF, IE 9,8 and problem is in IE7.

The question is :

Why does the position:absolute on

```
<div class="c-control-date-range-fields">.....</div>
```

behave as though the parent li.c-date-range-moreopt has position:relative, which is why I think it works as expected in FF and not in IE 7 ?

[image: Screenshot of expected behaviour, as it appears in FF & IE 9 & 8]

[image: Screenshot of the same in IE 7]

Comment: may we have a screenshot with IE7 ? You should play with `z-indexes` and set the `z-index` from the container on a heigh value.

Comment: Added the screenshot of the same page from IE7

Comment: I tried setting left:0 to the li.c-date-range-moreopt, it just moved the yellow box to the left:0 coordinate.

Comment: I thought this was an easy one for the gurus here :(. Somebody please give some clue.